# How i get source code in WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview

in onCreate()

```
    final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

         webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

                    String oAuthUrl="http://www.google.com";

                    if(url.contains(oAuthUrl))

                        webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {


                }
          });

         webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

MyJavaScriptInterface class

```
    class MyJavaScriptInterface
  {
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  public void processHTML(final String html)
  {
      Log.i("processed html",html);

        Thread OauthFetcher=new Thread(new Runnable() { 

            @Override
            public void run() {

                String oAuthDetails=null;
                  oAuthDetails=Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
                  Log.i("oAuthDetails",oAuthDetails);

            }
        });OauthFetcher.start();
    }
  }
```

I found that codes in stack overflow. I runned this app, but i doesnt get source code in my webview page. I want to get source code for webview and equal to String. How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you added `@JavascriptInterface` to processHTML method. If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public), have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface
{
  @JavascriptInterface
  public void processHTML(final String html)
  {
       Log.i("processed html",html);

       Thread OauthFetcher=new Thread(new Runnable() { 

        @Override
        public void run() {

            String oAuthDetails=null;
              oAuthDetails=Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
              Log.i("oAuthDetails",oAuthDetails);

        }
    });OauthFetcher.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is requiments API 17

Comment: You're targetting 17 or higher ? i presume

Comment: My App minimum SDK is API 8, @JavascriptInterface is requiments JELLY BEAN. Is there different method?

Comment: I know but it isn't about minSdk, what is your "targetSdk" ?

Comment: I'm sorry,my targetSdk API 21 LOLLIPOP

Comment: If your targetting Lollipop your method should look like (see my answer)